# Ruby command line option that lists operations to perform

Tags: ruby

Is it possible for me to do something like this:

```
>ruby some_file.rb
>Your options are:
> 1. delete file blah.txt
> 2. delete file blah2.txt
> 3. delete file blah3.txt
> x to exit
> 1
> blah.txt was deleted
> 1. delete file blah.txt
> 2. delete file blah2.txt
> 3. delete file blah3.txt
> x to exit
> x
>
```

And this would read it's configuration from a file which would have all the files to delete.

I want this to be in a loop, so it keeps asking what to do unless you press 'x'.

How could you do this in Ruby?

Comment: You should break this up into smaller questions like "how do I read user input" or "how do I read a configuration file" or "how do I make a loop".  You shouldn't expect someone to write your whole program for you.

Comment: Also, the ability to break a problem up into smaller pieces is a very important skill, and it will make you a better programmer.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the Ruby Toolbox for gems that would be relevant to this task? Also, "it's" isn't used when indicating possession - you should use "its" in that case. Only when you're doing a contraction of "it is" should "it's" be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can read user input from standard input using [`Kernel#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets). This should hopefully point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create the configuration file your talking about that has all of the files you
   need to delete.
2. Read the configuration file
3. Create a menu based on the configuration file
4. Read in user input and perform operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can start from here:

```
def menu(choice)
  case choice
    when 1 
      # do_something
    when 2
      # ...
  end
end

while ((a = gets) != "x\n")
  menu(a)
end
```

as @Hunter McMillen stated you can use some configuration file to create the case-when programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ARGV.size > 0
  if FileTest.exists? ARGV[0]
    files=[]
    IO.readlines(ARGV[0]).each{|l| files.push(l.chop) if FileTest.exists? l.chop}
    while files.size > 0
      files.each_with_index{|f,i| puts "#{i+1}. #{f}"}
      puts "x to exit"
      opt = $stdin.gets.chop
      break if opt == 'x'
      opt = opt.to_i
      puts "#{files.delete_at(opt-1)} was deleted" if opt > 0 && opt <= files.size && File.delete(files[opt-1]) > 0
    end
  end
end
```